# In Android RecyclerView How to change the color of Alternate rows

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am new in android , recently I have learned `recyclerview` and i want to change the color of rows.

Example:  I have 10 rows and I want to change color like 5 rows blue and 5 rows red.Alternate rows color should be like this.

From where I have to change this by Adapter or by MainActivity.
*Please help me*

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You can change the color of alternate row by adding the following code on your Adapter class.
You can also change the images of your row by using this code.

Put this code inside `OnBindViewHolder` in Adapter Class.

**JAVA:**

```
 if(position %2 == 1)
    {
        holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
        //  holder.imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
    }
    else
    {
       holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFAF8FD"));
       //  holder.imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFAF8FD"));
    }
```

**KOTLIN:**

```
if (position % 2 == 1)
 {
  holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"))
  //  holder.imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"))
 } 
 else 
 {
  holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFAF8FD"))
  // holder.imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFAF8FD"))
 }
```

Comment: what the holder is here?

Comment: `holder` is the first parameter in the `onBindViewHolder` method.

Answer (score 6):

In the onBindViewHolder of your adapter simply get the poisition and check that whether it is even or odd. If it is even, set the background color of your layout to red else blue

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

    if(position%2 == 0){
        viewHolder.containerLayout.setBackgroundColor(R.color.RED);
    } else {
        viewHolder.containerLayout.setBackgroundColor(R.color.BLUE);

    }}
```

Answer (score 2):

With CardView in Kotlin

```
 internal fun bind(d: Detalle, position: Int, listener: OnItemClickListener) {

        if (position % 2 == 1) {
            cardViewPrincipal.setCardBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(itemView.context, R.color.blue_logo))
        } else {
            cardViewPrincipal.setCardBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(itemView.context, R.color.colorWhite))
        }
```

Multiples Colors

```
when {
p % 4 == 0 -> cardViewPrincipal.setCardBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(itemView.context, R.color.yellow)) 
p % 4 == 1 -> cardViewPrincipal.setCardBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(itemView.context, R.color.green)) 
p % 4 == 2 -> cardViewPrincipal.setCardBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(itemView.context, R.color.blue)) 
p % 4 == 3 -> cardViewPrincipal.setCardBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(itemView.context, R.color.red)) 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe one problem with all of these solutions is that `onBindViewHolder` doesn't get called in certain cases. If you use notify methods like `notifyItemInserted(int position)`, you could potentially have rows stacked on top of each other with the same color - no good. You will need to call `notifyItemChanged` on every other item to re-render the background color corresponding to the new position.

Using the re-render all method `notifyDataSetChanged()` will fix this (but is less efficient than only updating specific rows), and if you don't dynamically change the contents of a `RecyclerAdapter` while the user is on the screen, you won't have this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Using Kotlin

```
    if (position % 2 == 1) {
        holder?.itemView?.setBackgroundColor(context.resources.getColor(R.color.text_gray))
    } else {
        holder?.itemView?.setBackgroundColor(context.resources.getColor(R.color.white))
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution :

```
LinearLayout ll_search =(LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ll_search);

if(position %2 == 1) {
  ll_search.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF")); 
} else { 
  ll_search.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#d3d3d3")); 
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow, and thank you for your answer. Rather than just posting a block of code, can you give a short explanation to what the issue is you solved and how you solved it? This will help people who find this question in the future to better understand the issue and how to deal with it.