# SetBackgroundColor for even items in RecyclerView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I want to `setBackgroundColor` for even items in my `RecyclerView`. I tried something like that in the`Adapter class`:

```
  override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ServersViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val server: Server = list[position]

        if (position % 2 == 0){
            holder.mConstraintLayout.setBackgroundColor(R.color.colorRed)
        }

        holder.bind(server)
    }
```

But it doesn't work fine. Could you help me?

EDIT

```
class ServerLisAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<ServersViewHolder>() {

    private var list = emptyList<Server>()

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ServersViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_server_list, parent, false)
        return ServersViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return list.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ServersViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val server: Server = list[position]

        if (position % 2 == 0){
            holder.mConstraintLayout.setBackgroundColor(R.color.colorRed)
        }

        holder.bind(server)
    }

    fun setList(serverList: List<Server>) {
        list = serverList
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the entire adapter class?

Comment: What is the exact problem your are facing?

Comment: @Antonio I made a short film: https://streamable.com/gncpj6

Comment: what is your problem ,any error or a crash ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Android RecyclerView How to change the color of Alternate rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46127942/in-android-recyclerview-how-to-change-the-color-of-alternate-rows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recycler view reuses the viewholders so you should be setting colors for both even and odd items:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ServersViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val server: Server = list[position]

    if (position % 2 == 0){
        holder.mConstraintLayout.setBackgroundColor(R.color.colorRed)
    } else {
        holder.mConstraintLayout.setBackgroundColor(R.color.normalColor)  // replace normalColor with your default color. 
    }

    holder.bind(server)
}
```

This will make the background color correct even if the view holder is reused.

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple solution.

this will help you to help to keep the instance while scrolling about the position

**Just declare a variable in your `modal` class like this**

```
data class Server (
    var isNumberEven: Boolean,
    //other params
)
```

now just use this loop before you set adapter

```
for(i in 0 until list!!.size){
            if ((i % 2) == 0) {
                // number is even
                list!![i].isNumberEven=true
            }

            else {
                // number is odd
                list!![i].isNumberEven=false
            }
        }
```

Now in your adapter use like this and set color

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ServersViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val server: Server = list[position]

    if (list[position].isNumberEven){
        holder.mConstraintLayout.setBackgroundColor(R.color.colorRed)
    } else {
        holder.mConstraintLayout.setBackgroundColor(R.color.otherColor)   
    }

    holder.bind(server)
}
```